# Where are my Eclipse projects?

Tags: android, eclipse, workspace

I have 3 Android projects in Eclipse, that I use in two synchronized computers. I always see my 3 project trees in the left frame (I think it is `Project explorer`).

But today, I opened Eclipse... and it shows nothing. The workspace path is correct, and the projects are there. I tried to (re)import the projects through `Import > Existing projects into workspace > Select root directory (= my workspace)`, my 3 projects appear in `Projects:`, but are greyed out. The message above the import window says

`Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace`

If they exist, why they don't appear in the `Project explorer` tab?

I tried a lot of things for an hour and googling without success.

This should be something terribly silly, I feel so stupid....

Comment: Can you try importing your project to the different workspace. At least you can continue you work

Comment: @Fahim: I deleted the `workspace/.metadata` folder and reimported all projects. All seems back to normal. Thanks!

Comment: Do not synchronize the entire workspace, it contains information (e.g. locations of things) specific to the machine on which it was created. Do it per-project.

Comment: @nitind: I see. In my case, everything is in my HOME directory, that is also synced, hence the whole workspace should be identical.

Comment: I'd remove the projects from the WorkSpace. Put them anywhere. Than re-import them from there.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this kind of problem.
I created a new worksspace and moved projects into it and re-imported from there.

Goto File->Switch Workspace -> Other and give your new workspace's path. after that move all your 3 projects into it.

tell me if it works.

Comment: Actually, as I answered above, removing the workspace/.metadata folder was easier, since reimporting everything is a one-click solution. But many thanks anyway!